# «Потерять смысл в беседе» и «не видеть смысла в дальнейшей беседе»?

Tags: семантика

Равны ли семантически данные выражения?

Answer (score 1):

Наталья, я думаю, что выражения не эквивалентны, даже не до конца синонимичны.

Первое предполагает, что изначально "смысл" все-таки был. 
В отношении второго этого сказать нельзя, может был он в *предыдущей* беседе, может и не было.

Плюс ко этому, второе выражение более удачно по стилистике и более жестко. 
"Потерял смысл" - это ведь не столь однозначно, может человек просто запутался в том, что ему говорят, о чем спорят, потерял *нить разговора* (хотя это немного странно было бы так выражаться).

Наверное правильнее было бы сравнивать семантику **"разговор потерял смысл"** и *"не видеть смысла в дальнейшем разговоре"*. Вот тут да, различия только те, что я уже обозначил: был ли смысл изначально или нет.

Comment: Не рассмотрены да значения: смысл как логика и смысл как польза, всё перемешано.  (А речь должна быть построена таким образом, чтобы было понятно, о чем говорится). В первом предложении разница этих значений не выражена.

Comment: А на кой шут рассматривать значения, которые тут в страшном сне не приснятся?

Comment: Это всего лишь Ваше мнение в ДИСКУССИОННОМ вопросе, хотя бы в ТАКИХ случаях научитесь уважать чужое мнение. Из двух значений (логика и польза) для разговора/беседы однозначно подходит "польза", также можно говорить о теме разговора/беседы, но выражение "смысл (логика) беседы/в беседе" не очень понятен.  И "потерять смысл (пользу)" в беседе несколько странно, поэтому первое выражение  мне кажется некорректным.

Comment: Sergey, не хотела влезать, но ваши "значения" тут действительно не к месту. Вопрос очевидно посвящен не разбору возможных хитромудрых толкований фраз, а совершенно очевидному противопоставлению формулировок с одним значением составляющего элемента. А то, что вам кажется некорректным одно из значений - этот вопрос вообще не поднимался. Ваше право.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны два выражения **с разным значением**:

1) Потерять мысль  в беседе (также: смысловую нить или нить разговора). Например: Совершенно потерял нить разговора и не знал, как его закончить.

Потерять смысл в беседе - неточное выражение, обычно так не говорят.

2) Не видеть смысла (пользы, прока) в дальнейшей беседе.

Из словаря:

СМЫСЛ,  1. Общее логическое содержание, несводимое к значениям составляющих его частей; основная мысль, суть, сущность чего-л. С. статьи. С. событий. С. / Разг. Польза, прок (в каком-л. действии, состоянии).